# Lumen - mongodb - jenssegers/laravel-mongodb - postman

Tags: php, mongodb, api, postman, lumen

i have install mongodb on my wamp, **C:\wamp64\bin\mongodb\mongodb.3.4\bin**, i have add mongodb in the path, and create windows service to launch it when necessary.
I have install lumen through composer, and after that i have install:

- **"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.3.*",**
- **"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.2.1",**
- **jenssegers/laravel-mongodb: "v3.1.3"**
- **"jenssegers/mongodb-session": "v1.1.0"**

Finaly i have install **mongodb.dll** on my wamp php and add extension=php_mongodb.dll inside the php.ini.
And now the extension on mongodb is active.

This is my User class:
[image]

This is my migration

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * The name of the database connection to use.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $connection = 'mongodb';

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::connection($this->connection)->
            table('Users', function (Blueprint $collection) {
                $collection->index('id');
                $collection->string('name');
                $collection->string('surname');
                $collection->unique('username');
                $collection->string('password',64);
                $collection->timestamps();
            });
        }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection($this->connection)
            ->table('Users', function (Blueprint $collection)
            {
                $collection->drop();
            });
    }
}`
```

This is the .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

MONGODB_HOST=localhost
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_USERNAME=joy
MONGODB_PASSWORD=mongo@ad@joy
MONGODB_DATABASE=brasserie
MONGODB_AUTHDATABASE=admin

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

i have create config directory in the root app, and i have add a database.php config file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [



        'mongodb' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
            'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD', 'testbrasserie'),
            'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE', 'synthese'),
           'options' => array(
                'db' => env('MONGODB_AUTHDATABASE', 'admin') //Sets the auth DB
            )//*/
        ),

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        ],

    ],//*/

];
```

I have enable eloquent, facades and jessenger Service provider. so this is my boostrap/app.php:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->withFacades();

// $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

// $app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
// ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);


if ($app->environment() !== 'production') {
    $app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
}

//class_alias ('Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model', 'Moloquent');
$app->register('Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider');

$app->withEloquent();
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/



$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

$app->configure('database');

return $app;
```

Here is my UsersTableSeeder:
[image]

I have launch the artisan migrate:install then artisan migrate and finally artisan db:seed and it seems to be ok, here is the result inside mongo:
[image]

Then i have create a UserController

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Joy_Admin
 * Date: 09/12/2016
 * Time: 23:23
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use DB;


class UserController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Pour recupérer tous les utilsateurs de la BD
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    }

    /**
     * Pour recupérer tous les utilsateurs de la BD
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function test()
    {

        return response()->json("it's ok");
    }

    /**
     * pour enregistrer un nouvel utilisateur dans la base de données
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User();

       $user->name = $request->input('name');
      $user->surname = $request->input('surname');
       $user->username = $request->input('username');
       $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->save();//*/


        DB::collection('Users')->insert([
            'name'     => 'name1',
            'surname' => 'surname1',
            'username'    => 'username1',
            'password' => Hash::make('password1')
        ]);
        return response()->json($user);

    }


    /**
     * On renvoit l'individu dans la BD
     * correspondant à l'id spécifié
     * @param $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function get($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        return response()->json($user);
    }

    /**
     * Mettre à jour les informations sur un utilisateur de la BD
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $user->username = $request->input('username');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

        $user->save();

        return response()->json($user);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->delete();

        return response()->json('Success');

    }
}
```

And finally update my routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;



$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});

$app->get('/api/users','UserController@index');
$app->get('/api/users/{id}','UserController@get');
$app->post('/api/users','UserController@create');
$app->put('/api/users/{id}','UserController@update');
$app->delete('/api/users/{id}','UserController@delete');
$app->get('/api','UserController@test');
```

I have launch postman, so that i could test my app, 
only **/api** work, all the other route give me the same error

1. [image: for $app->get('/api','UserController@test');]
2. [image: for $app->get('/api/users','UserController@index');]
3. [image: for $app->get('/api/users/{id}','UserController@get');]
4. [image: for $app->delete('/api/users/{id}','UserController@delete');]

***Could somebody help me fix the problem?***

Openssl and curl are active in my wamp php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the problem,
in my .env i was having:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

but in my project no configuration for them, so when i have change it into

```
CACHE_DRIVER=
SESSION_DRIVER=
```

everything works now.

[image]