# How to solve an error in Lumen related to Jenssegers/Mongodb?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, lumen

I am seeing this error when trying to access the Lumen application from the browser:

```
production.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php:84
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php(84): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8, 'Trying to acces...', '/var/www/vendor...', 84, Array)
    #1 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php(16): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->loadViewsFrom('/var/www/vendor...', 'pagination')
    #2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider->boot()
    #3 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #4 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
    #5 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
    #6 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(188): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
    #8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(551): Laravel\Lumen\Application->register(Object(Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider))
    #9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(325): Laravel\Lumen\Application->loadComponent('database', Array, 'db')
    #10 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(764): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array)
    #11 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
    #12 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('db', Array)
    #13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(221): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('db', Array)
    #14 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(1210): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('db')
    #15 /var/www/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/MongodbServiceProvider.php(16): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('db')
    #16 [internal function]: Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider->boot()
    #17 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #18 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
    #19 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
    #20 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #21 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(188): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
    #22 /var/www/bootstrap/app.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->register(Object(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider))
    #23 /var/www/public/index.php(14): require('/var/www/bootst...')
    #24 {main} {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /var/www/vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php:84)
```

The error goes away when removing the following lines from app.php:

```
//$app->register(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class);
//$app->withEloquent();
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
The Lumen / docker installation is based on this repo:
https://github.com/irfanbaigse/lumen-rest-api-with-docker

Comment: can you provide more details how have you set up Jenssegers in Lumen, also show your db configurations, https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#lumen see here for more details

Comment: Part 1
Thank you @bhucho I set it just like it's presented in the link you provided.
Also notice the lines I commented to the app working:
//$app->register(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class);
//$app->withEloquent();
I installed Jenssegers as part of composer.json "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.4"
I hope that information is helpful

Comment: Part 2
The DB configuration is as follows:
return [
    'default'     => 'mongodb',
    'connections' => [
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'options'  => [

            ],
        ],

Comment: please also tell your lumen version from conposer.json

Comment: follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103651/lumen-mongodb-jenssegers-laravel-mongodb-postman this question asker done all the steps(As I remember), if further error comes after even after following steps in the question then inform